# Installing git on macOS with Homebrew Error

Tags: git, macos, terminal, homebrew, macos-catalina

I had already installed HomeBrew on macOS but when I try to install git from the command:

```
brew install git
```

The terminal pops up with this error:

```
Updating Homebrew...

Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.  
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

I don't really understand what the program is really trying me to say. Any help with be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying run this command

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```